# Xcode find table view section row on detail text label

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath, sections

I have an index set up with my table and I am able to return the correct arrays for the textLabel.text according to the section header. My problem is I have an a separate array that i need to return in the detailTextLabel.text.

It just repeats in each section starting from the first index from the first section. For example:

**A**

Apple

*apple*

Alligator

*alligator*

**B**

Ball

*apple*

Bat

*alligator*

---

I've generated index characters and table headers. This is what I have to return the cell.

```
NSString *alphabet = [arrayIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
            //---get all of First array's beginning with the letter---
            NSPredicate *predicate =
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
            NSArray *firstArray = [First filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; 
            NSArray *secondArray = [Second filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; 

    if ([FirstArray count]>0) {
        //---extract the relevant state from the states object---
        NSString *cellValue = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



      //<--This line throws and error assuming it is trying to find the first letter to return the detail text -->  
    NSString *cellValueA = [secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//Returns value from first section and row in all section//
            //NSString *cellValueA = [Second objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
            cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellValueA;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
```

How do I find the matching row to the First Array to return the correct index in the Second Array. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You :-)

---

**FULL CODE**

```
-(void)loadSQL {
    // Path to the database
    NSString* dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DATABASE_NAME.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"databasePath: %@",dbPath);
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *firstString;
    NSString *secondString;

    // Open the database
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                              @"SELECT * FROM songs WHERE items LIKE %@ ", viewItems];

        const char *sql = [querySQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
        // Fetch all names
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Append each name
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                const char* cFirst = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStmt, 2);
                        const char* cSecond = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStmt, 3);

                if (cFirst == NULL)
                    // There should not be a NULL name
                    NSLog(@"Null name!!");

                else {
                firstString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cName];
                            secondString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cArtist];

                [First addObject:firstString];
                [Second addObject:secondString];


                    //[First release];
                    //[Second release];
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt); // Cleanup the statement
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving data from database.");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: Can't open database!");
    }

//Creating section with 1st letter of the First field//
    for (int i=0; i<[First count]-1; i++){
        //---get the first char of each state---
        char alphabet = [[First objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
        NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];
        //---add each letter to the index array---
        if (![arrayIndex containsObject:uniChar])
        {
            [arrayIndex addObject:uniChar];
        }
    }         
}





#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (searching)
        return 1;
    else
        return [arrayIndex count];
}

//---set the title for each section---
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (searching)
        return nil;

    else        
        return [arrayIndex objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (searching)
        return([searchedFirst count]);
    else{
        //return([First count]);
        NSString *alphabet = [songIndex objectAtIndex:section];
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
        NSArray *firstArray = [First filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        return [firstArray count];

    }
}

//---set the index for the table---
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (searching) {
        return nil;
    }

    return arrayIndex;
}


//return the cell info
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if(searching) {
        cell.textLabel.text =  [searchedFirst objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [searchedSecond objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    else{
        //---get the letter in the current section---
        NSString *alphabet = [arrayIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        //---get all states beginning with the letter---
        NSPredicate *predicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
        NSArray *firstArray = [First filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; 
        NSArray *secondArray = [Second filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; 

        if ([songArray count]>0) {
            NSString *firstValue = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *secondValue = [secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell.textLabel.text = firtValue;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = secondValue;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }

    }
    return cell;


}
```

Comment: This is more a meta-answer than an answer.  Trying to keep track of multiple arrays and relating them through an index number is a bad idea in general for exactly this reason.  Much better would be to create a custom object that has the information that you want for both `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` and a single array containing those objects.  That way, once you find the one object you want, you have **all** the pieces of information together.

Comment: hi thank you. can you give an example of this? I'm new to xcode. Here I've made separate arrays from an sql statement from 2 fields. I'm not certain on how to add these two.

Comment: If you can show the code that currently populates `First` and `Second`, I'll try to make suggestions for changing it.  (Basically, you want to create a new class that inherits from `NSObject` and contains two strings as properties. Then, instead of adding something to `First` and something else to `Second`, you put both those things into one of your new objects and save that to an array.)

Comment: ok I've added the code above. I think I'm trying to understand the concept of adding two separate arrays into one but still have it in the TextLabel and DetailTextLabel, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you need, but if you are looking for the index in the array of a given object, then you can use:

> **indexOfObject:**
>
> Returns the lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to a given object.
>
> ```
>    - (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
> ```

([ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:))

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question from comments about restructuring....

First, create a custom class:

```
// CellLabels.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CellLabels : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *secondText;
@end

//CellLabels.m
#import "CellLabels.h"

@implementation CellLabels
@synthesize firstText = _firstText;
@synthesize secondText = _secondText;
@end
```

Instead of `First` and `Second`, create and initialize one `NSMutableArray` called `cellData`.  Replace...

```
[First addObject:firstString];
[Second addObject:secondString];
```

...with...

```
CellLabels *labels = [[CellLabels alloc] init];
labels.first = firstString;
labels.second = secondString;
[cellData addObject:labels];
```

Then, your array filtering works by comparing "SELF.firstText" and your array references work by using:

```
CellLabels *labels = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = labels.firstText;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = labels.secondText;
```

(OK, I didn't check to make sure all that compiled but it should give you the idea.)

Comment: ok, thank you for that. I got that working I'm stuck at just calling the labels.firstText array for getting the first letters and returning the rows. I'm sure I will figure it out. :-)